# Can not insert a new text input value into db from laravel register form

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

In a laravel app I had run the command

> php artisan make:auth

and a laravel register form created successfully.

In mysql users' table I had added a proffession field of varchar datatype column and  190 length.

And I updated Auth/register.blade.php page to the following

register.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="proffession" class="col-md-4 control-label"> proffession </label>
 <div class="col-md-6">
 <input id="proffession" type="text" class="form-control" name="porffession" 
 value="{{ old('proffession') }}" required>
 </div>
 </div>
```

My RegisterController.php class

```
    protected function validator(array $data)
        {
          return Validator::make($data, [
               'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
               'phone' => 'required|string|max:255',
              'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
               'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
         ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
             'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

but when I click the submit button the proffession column value is always **null** although a new user added.

Comment: Where's your controller code?

Comment: Automatically I am drawn to: `name="porffession"` typo.. surely should be `name="proffession"` no?

Comment: I have updated my answer for you Webdev.

Comment: @Option It seems the problem from mission of proffession   RegistereController.php

Comment: Take a look at my answer webdev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your view code I can see that `name="porffession"` should surely be `name="proffession"`

Change your controller code from:

```
return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
             'phone' => $data['phone'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
```

to:

```
return User::create([
    'name' => $data['name'],
    'phone' => $data['phone'],
    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'proffession' => $data['proffession'],
]);
```

and fix the typo as mentioned above.

Also within the User.php model add `proffession` to the `$fillable` if you haven't already.

Comment: should I change this also ? return Validator::make($data, [
               'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'phone' => 'required|string|max:255',
              'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
               'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);

Comment: @WebDev, For testing purposes I wouldn't touch verification for now. Get it working first and then you can add it after.

Comment: 'profession' => $request->get('profession') where this statement to be?

Comment: @WebDev, I have revised and edited. I added that initially because you had no controller code. I have now removed. Replace the block coding as given above.

Comment: Now I get Undefined index: profession error when submitting form

Comment: @webdev, Did you fix the typo in the view and also add profession to your model User.php?

Comment: @webdev, my mistake sorry.. I put `profession` where as you are using `proffession` I have adjusted the code block accordingly. Please edit the code block with the updated version and then retry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167730/discussion-between-webdev-and-option).